# Best way to cut a sorted slice

Tags: arrays, go

I want to cut an array of integers before a specified value, and return an array containing those values and the remaining values in the array. We can assume the array is sorted. This is what I have so far:

```
func cutIntArrBefore(arr1 []int, n int) ([]int, []int) {
    arr2 := make([]int, 0, len(arr1))
    sliceIndex := 0


    for i, num := range arr1 {
        if num < n {
            arr2 = append(arr2, num)
            sliceIndex = i
        }
    }

    sliceIndex = sliceIndex + 1
    if sliceIndex >= len(arr1) {
        return arr2, nil
    } else {
        arr1 := arr1[sliceIndex:]   
        return arr2, arr1
    }
}
```

test code:

```
func main() {
    var arr1, arr2, arr3 []int
    arr1 = []int{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
    arr2, arr3 = cutIntArrBefore(arr1, 5)
    fmt.Printf("(%+v) = %+v, %+v\n", arr1, arr2, arr3)

    arr1 = []int{1,5}
    arr2, arr3 = cutIntArrBefore(arr1, 5)
    fmt.Printf("(%+v) = %+v, %+v\n", arr1, arr2, arr3)

    arr1 = []int{1}
    arr2, arr3 = cutIntArrBefore(arr1, 5)
    fmt.Printf("(%+v) = %+v, %+v\n", arr1, arr2, arr3)

    arr1 = []int{5}
    arr2, arr3 = cutIntArrBefore(arr1, 5)
    fmt.Printf("(%+v) = %+v, %+v\n", arr1, arr2, arr3)

    arr1 = []int{5,6}
    arr2, arr3 = cutIntArrBefore(arr1, 5)
    fmt.Printf("(%+v) = %+v, %+v\n", arr1, arr2, arr3)

    arr1 = []int{5,5}
    arr2, arr3 = cutIntArrBefore(arr1, 5)
    fmt.Printf("(%+v) = %+v, %+v\n", arr1, arr2, arr3)

    arr1 = []int{7,7,7}
    arr2, arr3 = cutIntArrBefore(arr1, 5)
    fmt.Printf("(%+v) = %+v, %+v\n", arr1, arr2, arr3)
}
```

output:

```
([1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]) = [1 2 3 4], [5 6 7 8]
([1 5]) = [1], [5]
([1]) = [1], []
([5]) = [], []
([5 6]) = [], [6]
([5 5]) = [], [5]
([7 7 7]) = [], [7 7]
```

Unfortunately, as you can see, if the first element is after the specified value, it gets skipped over. I want to do this as elegantly as possible. I'm hoping there's another way without having to create two arrays, or adding another if statement.

Comment: Since `[]int` is sorted, you can use [`sort.SearchInts`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#SearchInts), which performs a binary search (runs in logarithmic time, rather than linear).

Comment: there's also no need for `arr2`, just return the 2 slices, `arr[:i], arr[i:]`

Comment: Do you mean slices? Your code uses slices, but you talk about arrays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your implementation contains an off-by-one error, which can easily be worked around by using the index of the leftmost target value as the pivot point using the slice expressions `arr[:i]` and `arr[i:]`.

Also, consider using [`sort.SearchInts(...)`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#SearchInts) to find the target index in `O(lg(n))` time instead of `O(n)`. Using a builtin function will also likely improve legibility and maintainability of the code.

For example ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.com/p/8stD_wXHMrB)):

```
func cutBefore(xs []int, x int) ([]int, []int) {
  i := sort.SearchInts(xs, x)
  return xs[:i], xs[i:]
}

func main() {
  xss := [][]int{
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
    {1, 5},
    {1},
    {5},
    {5, 6},
    {5, 5},
    {7, 7, 7},
  }
  for _, xs := range xss {
    fmt.Println(cutBefore(xs, 5))
  }
  // [1 2 3 4] [5 6 7 8]
  // [1] [5]
  // [1] []
  // [] [5]
  // [] [5 6]
  // [] [5 5]
  // [] [7 7 7]
}
```

Comment: This is good advice but offers an unsolicited optimization while ignoring the actual question, which was due to an off-by-one error (it fixes the error, but doesn't mention it).

Comment: @Adrian thanks for the feedback; I've updated my answer.